# Is there any Javascript or React-Native equivalent syntax of this python code?

Tags: javascript, django, react-native

all.
I'm trying to post to my django REST server and following is python-version of how I post.

```
with open(some_image, 'rb') as f:
response = requests.post(
    url, 
    files={
        'image': f,
    }, 
    data={
        'longitude': SETTINGS[1]['long'],
        'latitude': SETTINGS[1]['lat'],
        'user_id': SETTINGS[1]['user_id'],
    })
```

I tried to do the same thing in react native ( javascript ), but it gives me errors. Following is my react native code:

```
upload = async () => { 
      let files = { 
           'image' : test // test is a base64 image file  
      }
      let data = { 
           'longitude' : location["longitude"],
           'latitude' : location["latitude"],
           'user_id' : "test_id",
 
      }

      postUrl = "someurl";
      axios.post(postUrl, files = files, data = data
      ).then( response => console.log(response)
      ).catch(function (error) {
           console.log(error.response);
           console.log(error);
      });
 }
```

The error status is 415 and it says "Unsupported media type "application/json" in request.

Comment: Your server trying to accept json data but you're giving it a invalid json use `axios.post(postUrl, files = files, data = JSON.stringify(data))`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use FormData to upload files.

[Click here for more details](https://www.bezkoder.com/axios-file-upload/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What about syntax? In python, requests.post has three params (two different objects (data, files) passes ) and how do I pass them in axios.post?

Comment: Dear answerer, You should also see how do I write a good answer [answer].